# I can´t import panda data reader as web. why? in jupiter notebook

Tags: pandas, datareader

I am newbie in Python.
I can´t import panda data reader as web.
why?
help me? please.

Thanks.
Sergio

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct sytax to import pandas data reader is

```py
import pandas_datareader.data as web
```

If you still recieve the same error then most likely you are missing `pandas_datareader` package. Please install it using `pip` command:

```
pip install pandas_datareader
```

Comment: WOW! it´s working now. Thank You for your help.

Tell me what´s the diference between its.

Comment: You had a typo in your statement `panda_datareader`, you missed a `s`.